# RewriteRule not working with virtual host

Tags: url-rewriting, xampp, virtualhost

I am facing an error when using xampp.

My site is ecom on localhost i.e., http://localhost/ecom. Similarly developing other sites say idiscuss  i.e., http://localhost/idiscuss.

```
In httpd.conf
----------------
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond C:/xampp/htdocs/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond C:/xampp/htdocs/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/ecom/(.*)$ /ecom/index.php?do=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

This condition removes .php extension as well as, directs every request to index.php, i.e., single entry point.

My file structure is
`C:/xampp/htdocs/ecom`, which in turn has `index.php` and other `php_class`, `js`, `css` folders.

Every time I have to access:

- localhost/ecom/                                  - for default home page
- localhost/ecom/contactus
- localhost/ecom/product

Instead, I want to use:

- ecom.com                                   - for default home page
- ecom.com/contactus
- ecom.com/product

To attain this,

```
a) in httpd-vhosts.conf
--------------------------
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ecom"

    ServerName ecom.com

</VirtualHost>

b) hosts file
-----------------
127.0.0.1       ecom.com

c) httpd.conf
---------------------
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond C:/xampp/htdocs/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond C:/xampp/htdocs/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^/ecom.com/(.*)$ /ecom/index.php?do=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

But it's giving absurd results.
I am only able to open the home page, i.e., ecom.com, but when trying to access  ecom.com/product, it says "requested url doesn't exist".

Moreover, when trying to access other sites that I am developing, e.g., localhost/idisucss, it throws the same error: "requested url doesn't exist".

I am completely stuck, any help would be appreciated.